# How do you modify configurations on IOP cluster for "BigInsights basic service plan" on BlueMix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights

I have applied "BigInsights basic service plan" on Bluemix and created a cluster. I want to add a custom coprocessor for HBase. However, I find that configurations in the Ambari Admin UI can't be modified, so I can't add the coprocessor.

So my question is how do you modify configurations and add a custom coprocessor for HBase?

Answer (score 0):

The BigInsights basic service plan provides Ambari Admin as a ReadOnly role, so the Ambari configurations cannot be modified. Questions like this one, about the Bluemix offerings, are best addressed on the [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html) forum. Stack Overflow is a great place for Bluemix programming questions.